# Retrieving map data as an image for a rosbridge app

Tags: navigation, mapping, rosbridge, map-server, move-base

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I am programming a javascript/rosbridge move_base interface to use with a tablet and I can successfully retrieve the map metadata by subscribing to the /map_metadata topic.  What I need now is the map image data (occupancy grid) in a format that I can use in my javascript program.

Currently I am using KineticJS to load the map image using a URL that points to the .png file that resides on the rosbridge webserver.  However, this requires knowing the name of the map file on the webserver and as far as I can tell, this filename is not published by the map_server. So I'd like to get the image directly from the /map topic.  I see that map_server provides a service called static_map which will give me the image.  But then I'm not sure how to turn this into an image object inside my javascript/rosbridge client.

Any ideas would be appreciated!

--patrick

http://www.pirobot.org

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/43977/retrieving-map-data-as-an-image-for-a-rosbridge-app/) by [Pi Robot](https://answers.ros.org/users/30/pi-robot/) on ROS Answers with karma: 4046 on 2012-09-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I found a workaround that doesn't require getting the image directly.  Instead I set the filename of the map as a parameter in the move_base launch file and then use the rosbridge get_param service to read the filename into my javascript client and KineticJS to get the image from the webserver.

---

Originally posted by [Pi Robot](https://answers.ros.org/users/30/pi-robot/) with karma: 4046 on 2012-09-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0